# Why would Smith want to get inside Zion and get free?

Tags: the-matrix

During his private interrogation with Morpheus, Smith reveals to him that Zion is going to be destroyed, so there will be no need for him to be in the Matrix.

But why would he want to get inside Zion? He would probably be eliminated together with the fallen Zion. Even if he somehow got free, would he survive in the form of a program residing in Zion's mainframe?

He associated his longed-for freedom with the access codes. Besides, he obviously didn't want to let the other agents know his real thoughts, so he ordered them out of the room.

Smith to Morpheus in M1:

> I can taste ... your stink. And every time I do, I fear that I have
> somehow been infected by it. It's repulsive. Isn't it?
>
> **I must get out of here. I must get free.** And in this mind is the key.
> My key.
>
> **Once Zion is destroyed, there is no need for me to be here.** Do you understand? I need the codes.
>
> **I have to get inside Zion**... ...and you have to tell me how. You're going to tell me... ...or you're going to die.

Smith's underlying motive to get the codes is clearly different from the other agents' assigned purpose.

Comment: Smith isn't a sentinel, he's a computer program that lives in the Matrix

Comment: Smith is a sentinel jacking in the Matrix. Remember he can order the strike. @Richard

Comment: The ability to communicate with the sentinels doesn't make him a sentinel

Comment: see http://www.matrixresolutions.com/matrix_system_agents.html @Richard

Comment: there's not a scrap of evidence that Smith is a Sentinel, other than his coordinating the attack from within the Matrix.

Comment: The link I gave says: this is also confirmed by The Matrix Online video game when the General (who commands red-eye Agents according to Agent Pace) says, "Not all bees follow the hive" (sentinels were purposely given a "buzzing" sound in the movies in order to creep people out more during sentinel scenes). @Richard

Comment: I agree with @Richard, there is zero in the movies that say Smith is a sentinal. *If he was a Sentinal he wouldn't be trapped in the Matrix and wouldn't need to free*.

Comment: Also, what use would an Agent be if they had to jack into the Matrix? They are essentially anti-virus software - they have to be active all the time to be effective.

Comment: Makes sense! What's your take on Smith's covert motive?  @DavidS

Comment: @kinzle-b Covert motive? There isn't one, he's being truthful - he hates being trapped inside the Matrix with humans. He finds them disgusting, and fears they have "infected" him with their stink. If he gets inside Zion (aka inside Zions computer network using Morpheuses codes) he can deactivate the defenses and the machines can walk right in and destroy the Resistance. No Resistance, no need for agents, so Smith can be released from the Matrix.

Comment: It's covert cause he didn't want other agents to know. He's being truthful to Morpheus alone. No need for agents means he could be deleted not released, since his purpose will become obsolete. How could he survive after the final attack on Zion? @DavidS

Comment: Related: *What's my motivation?* [Why do the Agents bother trying to get the Zion mainframe codes?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80285/why-do-the-agents-bother-trying-to-get-the-zion-mainframe-codes?rq=1)

Comment: Related, but not repeated; I'm more curious about Smith's unusual behavior and words. @Mazura

Comment: Technically, he's still *Agent* Smith at this point. He doesn't become Smith until the end of the first movie. That's an important distinction because he's still part of the system as long as he's an Agent.

Comment: I think there's a huge misunderstanding on what 'Deleted' means in terms of the Matrix, I don't think any sentient program is deleted as we think of it today. Deleted in this context could be interpreted as 'deleted from the matrix and return to the machine city to live on', Looking at it this way the movies make a lot more sense, also explains why sentient programs essentially commit suicide by choosing deletion - they are only deleted from the matrix and can now be back with their own 'people'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as the Agents are concerned, the codes aren't needed because they're trying to get *into* Zion, they're needed because it will help them to *destroy* Zion. To that end they need the codes to the mainframe in order to locate the city, and facilitate its destruction, presumably by shutting down their point-defenses, open security gates, etc.

Obviously (and wholly unbeknownst to the Zionese) the Machine Mainframe actually knows **full well where Zion is** and can wipe them out at any time of their choosing, regardless of the possession of the codes.

---

Since Smith's purpose is to destroy Zion, once that's achieved he can leave the "zoo" and return to The Source, something that's apparently both normal and highly desirable for programs whose functions are completed/obsoleted.

Comment: That was indeed what Smith wanted; see my edit. not my downvote, btw.

Comment: Hopefully a little clearer now

Comment: Yup, it's clearer. But you didn't address how Smith thought he could be freed if he got the codes. I think he could only be deleted afterwards, since the system would have no use for him. That was also his secret which he would only share with Morpheus. Returning to the source obviously is not the reason he could get freed. There must be another level of meaning. @Richard.

Comment: I got your point! "Once Zion is destroyed, there is no need for me to be here." That was actually what Smith wanted. He wanted to leave the Matrix, far from the stink that made him disgusted. I thought no need for him was his fear of becoming obsolete. Perhaps the only thing he didn't want to share with the other agents was his hatred for the Matrix. Ironically, he got free in a way he would never have expected, a virus.

Comment: Smith's purpose is to balance the equation.

Comment: you have edited the 'The Source' part since then. yesterday simply 'desirable' sounded like prestige. today 'normal' sounds like, well, normal. programs seems to know about returning. what makes you think programs find it desirable to return?

Comment: N611x007 - Rama and his wife make it clear that despite their small rebellion (having a child),  they have no intention of defying their core programming.

Comment: @Richard how is that -Kamala/Rama not defying their purpose- relevant to my question -what programs would find desirable in returning-?

Comment: @n611x007 - Their intent is to foster their daughter rather than becoming exiles themselves, despite the risk of being found out and getting derezzed.

Comment: Do you have anything to back up your second paragraph, about the fact that the machines knew exactly where Zion was the whole time (even if that's just a link to another Q&A I haven't found)? Not that I doubt you, but rather because I'm interested to know more about that...

Comment: @NathanS - The Architect states that Neo's task is to select individuals to help him to 'rebuild' Zion. The implication is that they're not going to build an entirely new city, they're going to 'discover' a disused Zion and use that as their base. It stands to reason that they can't know that the city was previously occupied and *repeatedly destroyed* so the machines must be repairing the damage they caused (in their attack) and resealing the city.

Comment: That almost sounds like the plot of the Mass Effect trilogy. Essentially pointing humans to a home for them to "discover" so that the machines know exactly where to look when the time comes to wipe them out and start it all over again.

Answer (score 13):

The matrix isn't the machine world, it is simply a simulation construct for the human mind. Smith wishes to leave the matrix so he can go on and be part of the machine world again, which he is not able to do while locked in the matrix. He wants a machine body and machine purpose that isn't baby sitting humanity and delinquent machines and as far as the machines are concerned the worst part of humanity and machine delinquents, those which are causing trouble.

Become human is just another form for him to multiply into in order to facilitate the desire to no longer need to be in a human form. He goes into the human world to cause trouble. Obviously he doesn't handle it very well and goes more insane rather than anything else. Being human and being a simulation of a human in the matrix aren't the same thing.

Comment: +1. You are the one to connect the dots. I really admire you! :)

Comment: There's no evidence that Smith wants a machine body. If anything, his goal is oblivion.

Comment: His goal is to get out of the matrix regardless whether that means oblivion or repurposing. That's not indicated nor hinted at in the story. I assume repurposing because the prime directive of life is to survive, but you could be right.

Comment: I would agree with Escoce because that's what Kamala and Rama-Kandra were supposed to do, namely returning to the machine world and fulfilling their purpose. I think Smith would wish the same. At least this answer is not a wild guess. @Richard

Comment: @Escoce - You seem to be mixing the Smith portrayed in the sequels with Smith, as portrayed in the original Matrix film. His motivations change dramatically after his encounter with Neo.

Comment: @Richard I don't think so, I am just saying it's possible you are correct. I however do not think you are about this.

Answer (score 3):

Did it cross your mind that Smith may actually be decadent and wishing for death?

Given Smith's attitude in the cited scene it may be the case. Maybe Smith wants to be released in a sense to transcend the Matrix via its (Smith's) death, or simply stop sensing.

Maybe Smith cannot die - even if it wants to? The system resurrects Smith each time it dies.

We cannot know for sure but if you consider that Smith had had enough with the Matrix already yet the Matrix resurrects Smith each time it dies, it makes sense. Maybe Smith doesn't care what happens with itself, just wants to let go.

Correspondingly, when the access codes are obtained, Smith can 'relax' and stop being in 'the zoo'.

I think Smith's behaviour and words in the sequels are aligned with this theory, especially the ending.

Comment: I don't think Smith knew the iteration of the Matrix at that moment. He only knew there had been a paradise Matrix which was too perfect to be accepted by human.

Comment: @KinzleB Smith doesn't need to know that iteration at that moment. The main point is that the Matrix resurrects Smith probably, when Smith gets hit by a train, when falling to its death, etc. No matter what, and Smith just wants to end that cycle, regardless of its life.

Comment: Since Smith didn't know the existence of the iteration, he would probably thought he could be retired forever once Zion was destroyed.

Comment: @KinzleB yes. I don't see your point with bringing up the iteration. I assume you mean the iteration of the matrix versions. Probably your concern is that I speak about the ending in the sequels. Let me clarify. I think when Smith talks to Morpheus it doesn't know about the iterations. Yet wants to die to be released. Once Neo destroys Smith the surprise of not being dead surprises Smith and thus its behaviour is changed. By the time of the ending obviously Smith knows more about the iterations but what I meant that its talking attitude at the ending still shows Smith's wish to be released.

Comment: But part of your answer is predicated on the premise that Smith knew the  iteration of the Matrix versions. That's why I brought up the concept.

Comment: @KinzleB [I think the Agents knew about the iterations of the Matrix.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80928/31936)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how Smith could die.  Agents don't seem to have bodies, they have to take over the body of somebody inside the matrix, and when *that* body dies, the agent program has to find another body to take over.  But in the second movie, Smith *does* suggest that he faced deletion, which he disobeyed, so something about how Neo defeated him in the first movie definitely was different than simply destroying the host.

Comment: @Null I see where you are coming from. Even Smith's upgrades don't seem to know about the iteration. Otherwise, why would agents bother doing things to make Neo's path so hard to walk. They could've just stepped aside to facilitate the normal function of the One. Besides, Smith being beaten by Seraph could well take place in the very version of the Matrix. And I think Escoce's answer clearly shows there's no need and possibility for Smith to get free if he knows his role will continue in the next cycle.

Comment: @KinzleB Agents oppose Neo because that is their *purpose*. Part of the function of The One is to *overcome* the seemingly invincible Agents. You are assuming that Agent Smith actually wants to "get free", but we can't trust that because he was interrogating Morpheus at the time.

Comment: @Null I disagree. If so, why would Smith order the other two out of the room? Smith is special because he's more sentimental than other agents. There's no need for him to lie. I don't think that's the intent of the directors. See Hypnosifl's answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89395

Comment: @Null He's disgruntled about his assigned job rather than keeping loyal to his job, so to speak. Out of the universe, not many people would lie about that, especially when they get emotional.

Comment: @KinzleB I've already expressed my disagreements with Hypnosifl's answer in the comments to that answer. I posted [my own answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/89541/31936) as well. The fact that Smith expresses how important his *purpose* is indicates that his "desire" to "get free" was all just an interrogation technique against Morpheus. If anything, he is more excessively devoted to his job than any other Agent due to his particular hatred of humans.

Comment: @Null I still don't buy your 'good cop bad cop' explanation. :)  Anyway, I like to hear different opinions, which make things more interesting. BTW, I'm not a native speaker. I hope I didn't make myself misunderstood.

Comment: @KinzleB which part of my answer relies on knowledge of iteration? Perhaps it's the 'transcend' part, is it not? I did not mean knowledge like Kamala/Rama-Kandra's by this. Quite the contrary. If Smith has out-matrix body, leaving is a matter of getting job done. If Smith has not, may have it as option, and the requirement may be the codes. A sobber variation of this if it is disallowed. Another option comes when Smith cannot get body. I call it death and/or transcendence. Death means to stop sensing. Transcendence means an *unexpected* sensing after death, ie. something not foreknown by Smith